# How do I get this code from Codepen to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/BrandonJF/pen/KGwyC

In case the page can't be accessed, a copy of the code is below.

Now, what I have been doing is using Brackets, and opening a folder in Brackets that contains a *completely blank* style.css page, *completely blank* init.js page, and an *almost* blank index.html page (this page at least has the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--

-->
<html lang="en">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>



    </body>
</html>
```

I paste the CodePen HTML in the body tag of index.html. I paste the CodePen CSS into style.css . I paste the CodePen Javascript into init.jss 
I have also tried pasting the CodePen Javascript into the body tag of index.html, using the tag "script" around the JS code.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

So Clueless!

CodePen HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <header>
         <h1>Task List</h1>
      <a href="#" id="clear">Clear all</a>

    </header>
    <section id="taskIOSection">
        <div id="formContainer">
            <form id="taskEntryForm">
                <input id="taskInput" placeholder="What would you like to do today?" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <ul id="taskList"></ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

CodePen CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400, 300, 600);
 * {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
body {
  background:url('http://dribbble.com/images/attachments/attachments-bg.png?1');
    background-color:#2a2a2a;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
#container {
    background-color: #111216;
    color:#999999;
    width:350px;
    margin: 50px auto auto auto;
    padding-bottom:12px;
}
#formContainer {
    padding-top:12px
}
#taskIOSection {
}
#taskInput {

    font-size:14px;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    height:36px;
    width:311px;
    border-radius:100px;
    background-color:#202023;
    border:0;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    padding-left:15px;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
}
#taskInput:focus{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1pt 1pt #999999;
 background-color:#111216; 
  outline:none;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #333333;
    font-style:italic;
    /* padding-left:10px; */
}
:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    color: #333333;
    font-style:italic;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: #333333;
    font-style:italic;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #333333;
    font-style:italic;
}
header {
    margin-top:0;
    background-color:#F94D50;
    width:338px;
    height:48px;
    padding-left:12px;
}
header h1 {
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:300;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:48px;
  width:50%;
  display:inline;
}
header a{

  width:40%;
  display:inline;
  line-height:48px;
}
#taskEntryForm {
    background-color:#111216;
    width:326px;
    height: 48px;
    border-width:0px;
    padding: 0px 12px 0px 12px;
    font-size:0px;
}
#taskList {
    width: 350px;
    margin:auto;
    font-size:19px;
    font-weight:600;
}
ul li {
    background-color:#17181D;
    height:48px;
    width:314px;
    padding-left:12px;
    margin:0 auto 10px auto;
    line-height:48px;
    list-style:none;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

CodePen Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        var taskID = "task-" + i;
        $('#taskList').append("<li id='" + taskID + "'>" + localStorage.getItem(taskID) + "</li>");
    }
    $('#clear').click(function () {
        localStorage.clear();
    });
    $('#taskEntryForm').submit(function () {
        if ($('#taskInput').val() !== "") {
            var taskID = "task-" + i;
            var taskMessage = $('#taskInput').val();
            localStorage.setItem(taskID, taskMessage);
            $('#taskList').append("<li class='task' id='" + taskID + "'>" + taskMessage + "</li>");
            var task = $('#' + taskID);
            task.css('display', 'none');
            task.slideDown();
            $('#taskInput').val("");
            i++;
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('#taskList').on("click", "li", function (event) {
        self = $(this);
        taskID = self.attr('id');
        localStorage.removeItem(taskID);
        self.slideUp('slow', function () {
            self.remove();
        });

    });


});
```

EDIT: To anyone who stumbles upon this post, here are the things that made my code work. As per jswebb's suggestion, I referenced what I needed in the head of the index.html.

So the head tag looks like this now:

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleok.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



</head>
```

Make sure that when you are writing the link tag, the href="YOURCSSFILENAME.css" includes all the correct folders!!!

Best wishes to all.

Comment: You should improve your question's title to start with.

Comment: *"Any ideas what I am doing wrong?"* ~ You didn't even describe a problem.

Comment: The problem is that the code isn't working in my Brackets project in the way that the code works on Codepen. There is no style applying to the box, and the functionality of the code is not working (can't add to the list).

Comment: Please fix your question by clicking the ["edit" link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29056779/edit) on your question and fully describe the expected results vs. the observed results.

Comment: Sherri, see my answer below - have you linked to the externally hosted jQuery library file, in the head of your HTML document?

Comment: jswebb, I didn't have anything in the head of the HTML document before, but now I've put the code you suggested. The functionality of the code is working now (can add to the list), but the style of the document remains bare.

Comment: Using a template as an example, I changed the head code to the following, but I still see no CSS applying.

    <head>     
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/init.js"></script>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <noscript>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-xlarge.css" />
  </noscript>

 </head>

Comment: Sherri, I updated my answer below, regarding linking to external CSS files. Link to your blank 'style.css' sheet in the HTML <head></head>, and then put the CodePen CSS into style.css.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CodePen you linked to utilizes jQuery; however, when using a text editor and writing to a blank HTML file, you need to link to the jQuery library - have you done this?

If not, place an external source link to the Google-hosted jQuery script file in between `<head>` and `</head>`, using the following:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Let me know if that solves the issue for you!

**EDIT:** To solve the CSS issue you are having, you need to follow the same procedure for the external sheet; in general, sandboxes allow functionality without linking different files, but when working in text editors, you must supply the connection between stylesheets, JS files and the HTML page.

To link to your external CSS sheet, put the following in between `<head>` and `</head>`:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

This is the standard procedure for adding links to external CSS. If the sheet is open in the Brackets editor, it should provide you with 'style.css' when you start typing it in.

Once you do the above, place the CSS from the CodePen into that CSS file, and then save all of the sheets you're working in. Everything should work - let me know if that solved your issues!

Comment: Thank you. I know that should work, but I'm still doing something wrong, somehow. This is very frustrating, haha.

The only files I have are:

init.js (completely blank)

index.html

style.css


The code for index.html is on the left and the code for style.css is on the right: http://i.imgur.com/aGH6xbb.png

sorry, I would upload the actual files but I don't know how

Comment: Perhaps that template you posted above could be causing issue? Have you erased that? If not, start with a fresh <head /> section and only post the jQuery and the link to your external CSS.

Comment: As a work-around (until you figure out the hiccup), you could always use <style></style> in the <head /> section, and put the CodePen CSS in between those. Embedding the style in the HTML page should work for you, if all else fails.

Comment: Putting the CSS code in <style></style> in the <head></head> section works PERFECTLY, and I can finally breathe some sigh of relief!!! 

Thank you very much, that will help me tons.

I am not sure if you saw, but I put an image link of my code in the edited comment above (yeah, I know... I couldn't figure out how to attach actual files here)... So if I could ask one last favor, maybe you could glance at those and see if you notice any obvious causes for the failure

Comment: I copied the above code exactly into Brackets, and it all worked for me, so it isn't a problem with the code. You'll have to go back through on your end and look for the issue - check to see that all of the files are saved (including the CSS), and then check to see if there any typos you might've overlooked.

Comment: Thank you for that info, and for all of your help. Best wishes. :]!

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that this issue was resolved. It turned out that I just needed to reference the folder the css file was in in that HTML tag. So this worked: <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleok.css" />

I'm just letting you know there was resolution, haha, and maybe helping anyone else who stumbles across this. Again, thank you so much for your help! Keeps me moving on.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same answer here:

[How do I take code from Codepen, and use it locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876904/how-do-i-take-code-from-codepen-and-use-it-locally)

Right click on the `result` frame and choose `View Frame source`. And you can copy the source code and paste it in your own text-editor.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: This really works, Viewing Frame source saves more time!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are not missing jQuery which is a dependancy for the javascript

While copying javascript from codepen, it was adding some addition checks whilst compiling the coffeescript. So just use http://js2.coffee/ in order to convert the coffeescript into javascript preview, which you can then use in your code.